# IntelliJ Idea 2016.1 does not read application properties

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot, intellij-idea-2016

I have a spring boot project that compiles and works fine when i run it from 2015.3 IDE but not from 2016.1, it crashes at startup but it is because the configuration seems to be broken.
What i have found is the following:

- it seems that from within the ide 2016 the application.properties
  file is not honoured, i can see in the app logs that the profile is not
  set, while an active profile is actually sets in the aforementioned
  file
- i can rebuild the project without problems
- the compiled jar works if invoked from command line
- the application.properties is in the src/main/resources folder (which is marked as a resource folder)
- the very same project works (always had) if i run it from 2015 IDEA

P.S. i am running the IDE on linux 64bit with oracle jdk 1.8.0.u77

Comment: Do you use Gradle?

Comment: yes, the project uses gradle

Comment: This is isolated to the linux build, seems to be working fine on Windows 64bit build IDE v2016.1.1. application.properties is being read correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. My colleague found workaround, where you need to switch from Gradle wrapper to use local installation of Gradle.

Also full rebuild is needed probably.

[image]

Comment: Thanks luboskrnac, that made it. Not sure what it was causing it though. I already had tried the full rebuild.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's workaround, not solution. I'm not happy that Gradle wrapper from repository is not used.